# Error running timer ‘lsp--on-idle’: (error "The connected server(s) does not support method textDocument/documentLink

Tags: spacemacs, c++

I'm trying to setup C++ IDE on spacemacs.

Below are the layers configured .

```
    dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
    '(
        helm
        (auto-completion :variables
                        auto-completion-return-key-behavior 'complete
                        auto-completion-tab-key-behavior 'cycle
                        auto-completion-complete-with-key-sequence nil
                        auto-completion-complete-with-key-sequence-delay 0.1
                        auto-completion-private-snippets-directory nil
                        auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup nil
                        )
        (lsp :variables
            lsp-ui-doc-enable t
            lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil)

        emacs-lisp
        c-c++
        (cmake :variables cmake-enable-cmake-ide-support nil)
        go
        java
        treemacs
        syntax-checking
    )
```

Below are the additional packages -

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(bazel-mode lsp-haskell ccls lsp-ui company-lsp dap-mode)
```

My c++ configuration layer settings are -

```
    (setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
                '((c-c++ :variables
                        c-c++-backend 'lsp-ccls
                        c-c++-adopt-subprojects t
                        c-c++-lsp-enable-semantic-highlight 'rainbow
                        c-c++-default-mode-for-headers 'c++-mode
                        c++-enable-organize-includes-on-save t
                        c-c++-lsp-cache-dir ".cache"
                        c-c++-lsp-extra-init-params '(:completion (:detailedLabel t) :index (:comments 2))
                        c-c++-lsp-sem-highlight-method 'font-lock
                        c-c++-lsp-sem-highlight-rainbow nil
                        )))

    (setq ccls-executable "/usr/bin/ccls")
    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'lsp)
```

After adding the below settings I'm getting below error -

**Settings**

```
    (setq ccls-executable "/usr/bin/ccls")
    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'lsp)
```

Error -

> Error running timer ‘lsp--on-idle’: (error "The connected server(s) does not support method textDocument/documentLink
>   To find out what capabilities support your server use ‘M-x lsp-describe-session’ and expand the capabilities section.")

I don't get this error for other programming languages like go, java etc
I only get this for C++.

What is wrong with my configuration? How can I fix this error?

Note:

My OS details -

```
    raj@localhost:~> lsb_release -a
    LSB Version:    core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch
    Distributor ID: openSUSE
    Description:    openSUSE Leap 15.1
    Release:        15.1
    Codename:       n/a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution from gitter.im. Setting the below in .spacemacs file worked

```
(setq lsp-enable-links nil)
```